# What are the properties of an Outlook .MSG file that Apache Tika can extract?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I am looking for a single list of all the properties of an  Outlook .MSG file that Apache Tika can extract  .  I only found one class , called org.apache.tika.metadata.Message .  However it only has five fields  - MESSAGE_BCC, MESSAGE_CC, MESSAGE_FROM, MESSAGE_RECIPIENT_ADDRESS, and MESSAGE_TO .

But I know there are others, because the Apache Tika example shows an example where we run a jar ( via >java `-jar tika-app-1.14.jar example_sent_regular.msg` )  and then it displays some more information - like date and Content-Length   .